# How can I make sure my code continues to loop while only accepting integer values from the user input?

Tags: python

Asked a question earlier today, but managed to figure out my answer from earlier after some goofing around.  I have a new question though.  I'm still really new to python, and I'm working on my first mid-term project.  My code currently runs exactly to the specifications the instructor has asked for, however I would like to add a little extra by making sure that the only input the code will accept from the user is an integer.  I've looked at a posts and seen *how* it can be done, but I don't quite understand yet.  Can someone show me how I would be able to write an exception handler into my code that continues to loop properly?

```
#will be used later to generate a random guess
import random

#Welcome Greeting
print("----------------------------------------------------")
print("Hello, and welcome to my Fall 2021 Mid-term Project.")
print("----------------------------------------------------\n\n")


#collect data for group size, give user the option to exit
groupSize = int(input("How many people are there in your group today? Or enter 0 to exit: "))  

while groupSize != 0:
    
    eachAge = 0
    
    #prep user to enter values
    print("\nWhy don't you tell me how old each person is?\n")
    
    for eachLoop in range (1, groupSize+1):
        
        age = int(input("# "+str(eachLoop)+" :  "))
        
        #make sure to add the ages of the group to each other to update the eachAge variable    
        eachAge += age
        
    #divide the total age by the groupSize variable and round to 3 decimals
    averageAge = round(eachAge/groupSize,3)   
    print("\nThe average age for this group is",str(averageAge)+".\n")
    
    #generate a random guess between 1-100
    randNum=random.randint(1,100)
    
    print("I was going to guess %0.3f"%randNum)
    if randNum < averageAge:
        
        #i'm creating variables to make the fomatting in my string simpler
        guessLow = float(averageAge-randNum) 
        print("\nI seem to have guessed too low, short by %0.3f" % guessLow)
        
    elif randNum > averageAge:
        guessHigh = float(randNum-averageAge)
        print("\nIt looks like I guessed too high, over shot it by %0.3f" % guessHigh)
        
    #this is extremely unlikely with the random guessing, I just thought it might be fun
    else:
        print("\nOh man, I guessed right on the money!")
        
    #time to categorize our averaged age groups
    if averageAge <= 19:
        print ("\nYou have a group of very young people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 20 and averageAge <= 44:
        print ("\nYou have a group of young people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 45 and averageAge <= 59:
        print ("\nYou have a group of middle aged people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 60 and averageAge <= 74:
        print ("\nYou have a group of young elderly people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 75 and averageAge <= 90:
        print ("\nYou have a group of elderly people.\n\n")
    else:
        print ("\nYou have a group of long-lived people.\n\n")
        
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    print("Why don't we give it another shot? Let's start over.")
    print("----------------------------------------------------\n\n")
    
    #reinitialize value back to 0 so that the program can run again from the beginning
    groupSize = int(input("How many people are there in your group this time? Or enter 0 to exit: "))

if groupSize <= 0:
    print("\n\n\n-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`Thanks for trying out my program!`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to continuously prompt the user until they enter an integer (or an exception is thrown, like `KeyboardInterrupt` if they press ctrl C):

```py
def read_int(msg):
    while True:
        val_str = input(msg)
        try:
            return int(val_str)
        except ValueError:
            print('%r is not a valid integer' % val_str)

x = read_int('Please enter an integer')
print('user entered %d' % x)
```

The way it works is by calling `input` and converting it to an `int`, like you are doing. But using try/except, it handles the case where `int(val_str)` throws an exception if the input is not a valid integer. Normally the program would end and print the stack trace in that case, but if we catch it then we can do whatever we want: in this case, loop and call input again.

The loop ends when we `return`. You could also `break` if this is not inside its own function.

## Without functions or try/except

For the purposes of learning, one way of doing it without functions or try except could involve manually checking if the string is a valid integer (but thanks to [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for pointing out that I first missed negative numbers, and that the python `int()` can handle far more than ascii 0-9 with an optional negative):

```py
val_int = None
while True:
    val_str = input(msg)

    # Below is a crude way to implement
    # the regex '[+-]?[0-9]+'

    # make a copy of the string so that we can modify it
    val_str_test = val_str
    is_valid_int = True

    # allow negative numbers in subsequent checks
    # by removing the leading unary negative/positive if it exists
    if len(val_str_test) > 0 and val_str_test[0] in [ '-', '+' ]:
        val_str_test = val_str_test[1:]

    # check if all characters in the string
    # are between 0 and 9, to ensure this is a valid integer
    for c in val_str_test:
        if not('0' <= c <= '9'):
            is_valid_int = False
            break

    # empty strings are also not valid integers, but wouldn't
    # be caught by the above loop
    if len(val_str_test) == 0:
         is_valid_int = False

    # if the user's string is not a valid integer,
    # then loop to the beginning where we prompt the user to
    # enter a string
    if not is_valid_int:
        continue

    # I am pretty sure that in this case, int(val_str)
    # can't throw an exception, besides maybe
    # running out of memory or something outside the scope
    # of this question
    val_int = int(val_str)
    break
```

Comment: defining functions and using the try/except setups are something we haven't learned yet. That's what I was seeing in my search earlier.  I'll start doing some research into how to use them, I appreciate the input!

Comment: @SnazzyJoe I added an example of how you could do it without functions or try/except, by checking if the input is valid before hand. In general this is probably not a great way of doing it, but since you're learning it might help.

Comment: You are too restrictive in your attempt to avoid `try/except`. You aren't accepting negative integers, and you aren't accepting non-ASCII characters that `int` can handle just fine (e.g., `int('੨') == 2`). You may not raise an exception, but you will generate a lot of false negatives.

Comment: @chepner good point about negative numbers, and to my surprise, unary positive is also handled by int(). I also had no idea that characters besides `-?[0-9]+` were handled by int(), but I think that's outside the scope of the OP's question (though I added an edit to point it out and credited you)

Comment: @chepner where can I read more about how `int('੨') == 2` works? I don't see anything about it in the [python 3.6 documentation for int](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int), but it seems to work in python 3.6 for me.

Comment: That's just the Devanagari numeral 2. `int` will accept a large number of Unicode characters designated as numbers. I'm not sure it's explicitly documented, or if it's a CPython implementation detail.

Comment: I really appreciate the assist @axby, I need to start researching defining functions and stuff. It's hard to find the hours in the day while being a fulltime student who works in all the other available hours.

Comment: You're welcome @SnazzyJoe, and don't forget to upvote/accept answers that you found helpful. In my experience, it can be difficult to wrap your head around some programming concepts at first, but eventually they just click (especially when learning something new that helps you understand how something you learned about a while ago really works at a lower level). Good luck!

Comment: The moment I'm able to upvote, the moment I'll start upvoting haha. I've only been a member for a few days and haven't built up enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Set a function to reprompt the person for a number:

```
def get_number(question):
    value = input(question)
    while 1:
        try:
            value = int(value)
            break
        except:
            value = input(f'(must be a number) {question}')
    return value

groupSize = get_number("How many people are there in your group this time? Or enter 0 to exit: ")
#or
age = get_number("# " + str(eachLoop) + " :  ")
```

Your entire code would look like this:

```
# will be used later to generate a random guess
import random

# Welcome Greeting
print("----------------------------------------------------")
print("Hello, and welcome to my Fall 2021 Mid-term Project.")
print("----------------------------------------------------\n\n")

# collect data for group size, give user the option to exit

def get_number(question):
    value = input(question)
    while 1:
        try:
            value = int(value)
            break
        except:
            value = input(f'(must be a number) {question}')
    return value

while 1:
    groupSize = get_number("How many people are there in your group this time? Or enter 0 to exit: ")
    if groupSize == 0:
        break
    eachAge = 0

    # prep user to enter values
    print("\nWhy don't you tell me how old each person is?\n")

    for eachLoop in range(1, groupSize + 1):
        age = get_number("# " + str(eachLoop) + " :  ")

        # make sure to add the ages of the group to each other to update the eachAge variable
        eachAge += age

    # divide the total age by the groupSize variable and round to 3 decimals
    averageAge = round(eachAge / groupSize, 3)
    print("\nThe average age for this group is", str(averageAge) + ".\n")

    # generate a random guess between 1-100
    randNum = random.randint(1, 100)

    print("I was going to guess %0.3f" % randNum)
    if randNum < averageAge:

        # i'm creating variables to make the fomatting in my string simpler
        guessLow = float(averageAge - randNum)
        print("\nI seem to have guessed too low, short by %0.3f" % guessLow)

    elif randNum > averageAge:
        guessHigh = float(randNum - averageAge)
        print("\nIt looks like I guessed too high, over shot it by %0.3f" % guessHigh)

    # this is extremely unlikely with the random guessing, I just thought it might be fun
    else:
        print("\nOh man, I guessed right on the money!")

    # time to categorize our averaged age groups
    if averageAge <= 19:
        print("\nYou have a group of very young people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 20 and averageAge <= 44:
        print("\nYou have a group of young people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 45 and averageAge <= 59:
        print("\nYou have a group of middle aged people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 60 and averageAge <= 74:
        print("\nYou have a group of young elderly people.\n\n")
    elif averageAge >= 75 and averageAge <= 90:
        print("\nYou have a group of elderly people.\n\n")
    else:
        print("\nYou have a group of long-lived people.\n\n")

    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    print("Why don't we give it another shot? Let's start over.")
    print("----------------------------------------------------\n\n")

if groupSize <= 0:
    print("\n\n\n-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`Thanks for trying out my program!`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-`-")
```

Comment: I really appreciate this.  As a beginner, seeing the different styles and ways things can be done is starting to help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So I read a bit about using Try and Except and came up with this:

```
while True:
    try:
        groupSize = int(input("How many people are there in your group? Or enter 0 to exit. "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("\n**Please enter an integer value only.\n**")

while groupSize != 0:
    
    eachAge = 0
```

The rest of the code remains unchanged from what I did earlier until the end of the loop when I basically redo the same try/except handler to re-initialize the groupSize variable back to a user input.

Comment: If you nest this into a function (like I did) you can use it for all your inputs.  And not repeat code...

Comment: Attempting to create functions is next on my personal project list! That will start to really clean up my code and make it easier/less repetitive